# Jupyter Notebook: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cfuzzyset'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

first, sign up on dataverse and get an API key

note: the search parameter can be improved

```
import urllib.request
import json
from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultfirsdict
from IPython.core.display import HTML
from cfuzzyset import cFuzzySet as FuzzySet
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-daa2bf7943d0> in <module>()
      4 from collections import defaultdict
      5 from IPython.core.display import HTML
----> 6 from cfuzzyset import cFuzzySet as FuzzySet

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cfuzzyset'
```

Comment: Hello, I am running this code in jupyter notebook for dataverse dashboard curation but I am getting this error everytime. Does anyone know about this cfuzzyset module?

Comment: I just pinged the developers of the dataverse-dashboard-curation project: https://github.com/bioversity/dataverse-dashboard-curation/issues/3

Comment: I installed the fuzzyset module but still getting an error while adding a list to it. Code:github.com/bioversity/dataverse-dashboard-curation

Answer (score 0):

This is the python module that is used in the code and that you need to install: https://github.com/axiak/fuzzyset

Comment: Though this might be a solution to OPs question, you might consider posting more information to support this  as answer, Link only asnwers are not appreciated as answers.

Comment: I installed the same and its giving me error in agrovoc mapping 'expected list,got dict values'. The code is here:https://github.com/bioversity/dataverse-dashboard-curation